# Inconsistent innerText for contenteditable div across browsers

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, contenteditable, innertext

I want an auto-growing textarea. I'm exploring the `contenteditable` `div` approach. If I can't get this to work, I'll fallback to `textarea` with javascript, but that's another story.

Is this hopeless? Do you have some insight or tips?

- Run the code snipped, click the middle of the yellow div and press Enter 1x. Observe the differences in innerText across browsers.
- After hitting Enter, in Firefox there is suddenly only one trailing space on the first line, instead of two.
- In Edge I get 1, in Chrome 2 and in Firefox 3 newline characters, while the display only shows 1 empty line in all cases.
- Setting the `innerHTML` to the value of the `innerText` property results in even more astonishing differences (see the images on the right side): Edge lost a line, firefox gained a line . And I wasn't even able to test Safari yet. Edge seems to display a newline character a a space in the console ‍♂️.

```html
<!-- https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/83-4-ways-to-convert-string-to-character-array/ -->
<div id="a" contenteditable="true" style="display: block; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 4px; background: yellow;">a  </div>
<button onclick="console.log([...document.getElementById('a').innerText])">innerText</button>
<button onclick="console.log([...document.getElementById('a').innerHTML])">innerHTML</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = 'a  '">Reset</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = document.getElementById('a').innerText">Set innerHTML = innerText</button>
```

[image]

Comment: i can't understand what's the point of this "incoherent" behavior... i mean, what problems will  be caused this incoherence on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to edit a value from a database, so i need 2-way binding. Setting from database and display, then edit, then get it and save it back to the database.

Comment: Well for displaying, i don't think that there is a problem, you probably need only to replace each `\n` with `<br>`, and for the saving, i think that you can just trim the beginning and the end?...

Comment: I need the trailing whitespace on each line, as well as trailing new lines.